# Android: Navigation Drawer. How to create a fragment back stack when opening the app from a notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification

Ive been working with the Drawer pattern for a while but I feel I don't have a good way to solve the next problem. Let's imagine a very simple app using the Navigation Drawer patter. To make it simpler the app has a welcome screen (initial fragment) and only one option ("messages") is present on the drawer.

Clicking on **messages** item will add a new transaction and a new fragment will be shown (a list of messages). Just as before, touching a message on the list will also produce a new transaction and show a new view with the message details.

At this point if I hit the back key all works. I can navigate back to the list of messages, then to the welcome fragment and finally the app closes if I hit it one more time.

For me, it gets really messy when for example I receive a push notification pointing to a specific message. I hope you can see where I'm going ! I need to create the activity and create a "**fake**" stack to provide user's with the correct back navigation, but I really don't know how to face this issue. Saying it with other words: I need to create entries on the stack for the **welcome fragment** and **the message list fragment**.

My question is: is there a standard way to do this ? It's entirely possible I'm missing something but I haven't really find something to generate this synthetic stack to provide a correct navigation. I'm also sure there may be a different approach on how to solve this and I may not know about.

In any case, thanks in advance.